# Webservices - called using HttpUrlconnection and JAX WS RI

Tags: jaxb, jax-ws

In my project, we consume webservices . What was confusing to me was there were some webservices(say `A`) that were called just using the `HttpURLConnection` and req/response was marshalled/unmarshalled using JAXB

There is another web service(say `B`) for which i see many classes with JAX WSRI and its not called using `HttpURLConnection`. I also see .wsdl files for these webservices.

```
/**
* This class was generated by the JAX-WS RI.
* JAX-WS RI 2.1.1 in JDK 6
* Generated source version: 2.0
* 
*/

@WebService(name = "ABPortType",     targetNamespace        "http://www.ups.com/WSDL/XOLTWS/DCR/v1.0")
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
public interface ABCPortType {
@WebMethod(operationName = "ProcessAB", action  =      =   "http://example.com/webservices/xxBinding/v1.0")
@WebResult(name = "xxResponse", targetNamespace =    "http://xx.com/XMLSchema/XXWS/AB/v1.0", partName = "Body")

}
```

MY doubts are

1. Why are we calling the webservice `B` with all these extra bloat (end point, JAX WS RI instead of using `HttpURLConnection`?
2. can `HttpULConnection` be used to call this webservice `B`
3. For webservice A  that is called using `HttpURLConnection` there is no WSDL (just jaxb classes created from xsd) but whreas the WS that is called using  JAXWS RI generated classes has a WSDL. Are the web service A and B implemnted differentely and thats why we call them in different ways

Please help me understand

-Venkat

Answer (score 0):

According to the order of your questions:

1. If you are using [JAX-WS API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_XML_Web_Services), may be you want to generate client proxy classes from the WebService, e.g. using the [`wsimport`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html) tool for generate the client stubs from the WSDL document file. So that you work with Java objects and not with XML. Only in special cases, you need a XML handler for advanced features, such as WS-Security.
2. Yes. You need to work with the XML directly and use JAX-B for marshall/unmarshall the messages.
3. The WSDL document file describes the SOAP service and the signatures of all the operations available in the service. If `A` does not have a descriptor (the WSDL document file), may not use the JAX-WS API, e.g.  [Java WSDP](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/webservicespack-1-140243.html), or the service provider is not exposing the WSDL.

Comment: So it depends on how the service provider wants his webservice to be accessed. Either he exposes a WSDL file and we generate client stubs out of it to call the WS (or)  the service provider gives the request /response XSD and we work with XML directly using JAXB. IS there any other way that the service provider can expose hsi service.

Comment: For the WSDL exposed WS it has 3 schemas say Schema 1, Schema 2 and Schema 3 defined within it.

Schema 1 in Target_namespace_1
Schema 2 in Target_namespace_2
Schema 3 in Target_namespace_3

When i run the WSImport in cmd line on the WSDL file , it creates java artifacts in folders namely

Target_namespace_1, Target_namespace_2,Target_namespace_3. 

This same WSDL is used in another project and all the artifacts appear in a single package.

I have tried using the options in wsimport.exe but still not able to generate all the packages in a single package. I have tried all options but no luck